# Importing and using NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ejs

I am trying to use a node module called "tagify" in my node.js app. In the readme file for the package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yaireo/tagify#installation) it says to setup as follows:

```
npm i @yaireo/tagify --save

// usage:
import Tagify from '@yaireo/tagify'

var tagify = new Tagify(...)
```

I ran the npm command and it installed fine. My EJS file has this (not shown is the input name="tags" element):

```
<script>
    import Tagify from '@yaireo/tagify';

    var input = document.querySelector('input[name=tags]'),
    // init Tagify script on the above inputs
    tagify = new Tagify(input);
</script>
```

When I load the page, I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (reference to 'import' line)
```

I'm very new to this and very confused. I've been searching the internet for two hours and can't figure out the basic task of getting this package to work. If this questions is redundant, please direct me elsewhere, because I don't know where to go.

Comment: Drop the <script></script> tags. You don't need them in node.

Comment: @basic Tried it, but it's an EJS file (think HTML) so it needs the script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@yaireo/tagify@2.9.7/dist/tagify.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var input = document.querySelector('input[name=tags]'),
    // init Tagify script on the above inputs
    var tagify = new Tagify(input);
</script>
```

This code is not raw. you need to use technologies like babel or webpack to use it. easy to run this link will be enough

Comment: That link worked. Another huge error I discovered was that my script tag was at the top of the EJS file and needed to be at the end  for the querySelector to work. Thanks!